# Building GCC Cross-Compiler on cygwin for PowerPC

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, cross-compiling, powerpc

I have been trying to build a GCC C language cross-compiler for Powerpc-eabi architecture using Cygwin on Windows 7 32bit.

Following the instructions on http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler  when I execute the command

```
make all-gcc
```

after a while, the following error is generated.

```
...
g++ -c-g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti 
-fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual 
-Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long 
-Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H 
-DGENERATOR_FILE -I. -Ibuild -I../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc 
-I../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/build -I../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/../include  
-I../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/../libcpp/include
-o build/genpreds.o ../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/genpreds.c
In file included from ../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/rtl.h:26:0,
                 from ../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/genpreds.c:27:
../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/real.h:43:35: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
 #define SIGSZ   (SIGNIFICAND_BITS / HOST_BITS_PER_LONG)
                                   ^
../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/real.h:56:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘SIGSZ’
   unsigned long sig[SIGSZ];
                     ^
../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/real.h:56:26: error: size of array ‘sig’ is not an integral constant-expression
   unsigned long sig[SIGSZ];
                          ^
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2429: build/genpreds.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/build-gcc/gcc'
make: *** [Makefile:4100: all-gcc] Error 2
```

The cause of error seems to be the missing definition of HOST_BITS_PER_LONG in file rtl.h.

The configure command is

```
../gcc-5.4.0/configure --target=powerpc-eabi --prefix=/home/user/opt/cross --disable-nls --enable-languages=c --without-headers
```

I have binutils-2.26.

Gcc version 5.4.0 is the latest edition available from the Cygwin Package List.
I have also tried using gcc-6.1.0 getting the same error, plus other errors.

I think the configure command was not executed correctly.

Do you have an idea on how to resolve the problem, please?

```
  [1]: http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler
```

Comment: have you looked at config.log for any hint ?

Comment: Try removing the `-pedantic` option.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, @matzeri. I do not get any hint from the config.log file. The -pedantic option does not exist neither in the make nor configure commands. From which command I should remove the -pedantic option, please?

Comment: Look on your log. `-pedantic` is present in the g++ invocation so it must be present in one or more of the Makefiles.

Comment: In ../../gcc-5.4.0/gcc/makefile I found and removed the option -pedantic from STRICT_WARN = -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings, and I still get the same error.